# Django TypeError when trying to save the model

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I am trying to create a todo add but when I try to save my model it says todo got an unexpected keyword argument .

```
TypeError at /
todo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

it throws the following error

My models.py

```
class todo(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField()
   date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
   is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username + self.title
```

And my views looks like this

```
def todo(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    todo_list = todo(user=request.user, title=title, description= description)
    todo_list.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
return render(request, 'main/todo.html')
```

Please help me out

Comment: Your model and view _both_ are named `todo`, i.e. you are simply _recursively_ calling your view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your model and the view are named `todo`, so if you call `todo` in that view, the function will override the model, and thus make a recursive call.

You can import `todo` with a different name, like:

```
from app_name.models import todo as todo_model

def todo(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    todo_list = todo_model.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        title=title,
        description= description
    )
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
return render(request, 'main/todo.html')
```

But according to the [**PEP-8** style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), classes are written in `PerlCase`, *not* `snake_case`. You thus might want to rename your model to:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField()
   date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
   is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username + self.title
```

and then you can work with:

```
from app_name.models import Todo

def todo(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    todo_list = Todo.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        title=title,
        description= description
    )
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
return render(request, 'main/todo.html')
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.